# Are there FAA rules about changing an airport name from Municipal to Regional?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, terminology

Are there any FAA requirements to be met or stipulations for an airport to change its name from Municipal to Regional?

Answer (score 2):

In general there are no strict rules on airport names. This would be more of a marketing decision, and it's up to the owners/operators to decide of the expense of the "rebranding" is worth the benefits.

US regulations do cover international airports, and the [Secretary of the Treasury designates the official list of airports](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/granule/CFR-2012-title19-vol1/CFR-2012-title19-vol1-sec122-13). Even then, there are plenty of international airports not on this list, and [there are even some airports called "international" with no customs facilities](http://missoulian.com/news/local/not-all-montana-airports-fit-their-names/article_a615ff36-c66e-5f4d-9f5b-6b0a980e5bc8.html) or plans to have them in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAA does outline what a regional airport is here](https://www.faa.gov/airports/planning_capacity/passenger_allcargo_stats/categories/)

> **Regional**:
>
> Supports regional economies by connecting communities to statewide and
>   interstate markets.

There is also a lot of interesting info on [regional airports here.](https://www.faa.gov/airports/planning_capacity/ga_study/media/2012AssetReport.pdf#page=8) However neither of those documents cover the "Municipal" designation.

Comment: Those definition seem to be more in support of the study to guide regulations and funding, not really an impact on naming. Their example of a regional airport is named a municipal airport.